# Garmin watch with vs without maps

Tags: mountaineering, maps, gps, electronic-gear

I'm looking to get a new Garmin wristwatch.

Broadly, I'm looking at the Garmin Instinct 2/solar and the fenix 6.

Neglecting the price differential, the main difference seems to be that the fenix has 1. Maps and 2. Color screen.

Specifically for multi day mountaineering expeditions, how useful is the maps feature? In general, teams have 1-2 handheld Garmin navigation devices, so it's not a must have. But is the maps feature actually usable/useful on watches? One difference I've read is that having maps allows better altimeter calibration with GPS data. But I guess I could also calibrate altitude manually using the handheld device. Are there any other use cases I'm forgetting?

Comment: If you haven't found it already, check out [DCrainmaker.com](https://www.dcrainmaker.com/2019/08/garmin-fenix6-pro-solar-series-review.html) for pretty comprehensive reviews on sports watches - might help your decision.

Comment: The map is small, to me the main value in having it is that it's a backup for the primary map that's on my phone.

Comment: @LorenPechtel how useful is it, if it's so small?  Could you actually navigate back to safety on it if your phone died and you were lost already?  Properly in the wilds I'd have a paper map and a compass; GPS coordinates on the watch would be a nice addition to that, tiny maps much less so.

Comment: @bob1 I have seen his reviews. They are very good, probably the best online. But I don't think he does 2-4 week trips to remote areas devoid of electricity and with mostly unmarked trails. That's the specific use case I am looking at rn.

Comment: @ChrisH I've never tried to use it navigate but I do know it's good enough to give me a pretty good idea of where the terrain will let me through.  I should probably try finding my way back with it and see how well it works.

Comment: @LorenPechtel whether outdoors or at a computer, I never trust an untested backup!

Comment: @ChrisH I know the mapping works.  I just haven't tried actually using it.

Comment: @dakini have you dug into the Fenix specs and worked out if the combination of battery and solar would meet your use case? Or would you expect to charge it somehow?  I couldn't fancy a backup that would only last the trip if it got plenty of full sun every day.

Comment: @LorenPechtel that's what I'm getting at - there's working as in functional, and working as in useful to get you out of trouble in an unfamiliar area (I had a major reroute on a bike ride on Saturday; the mapping on my phone worked very well indeed, but with many fewer pixels it would have been much harder)

Comment: @dakini I think that the base fenix6 might not have maps natively, but it looks like you may be able to use the functionality via upload. The pro version seems to do maps natively (i.e. come preinstalled). Garmin charges for their maps, but the DCrainmaker link I gave above has a link and instructions to do it for free. The Instinct doesn't have maps, only breadcrumb/trackback (find your way back) so definitely less capable. However, the Instinct solar version is entirely possible to charge only on solar, which Fenix won't I think.

Comment: @bob1 Yeah, I have the pro version--if you want the extended battery life you have to go with the pro version.  The solar option doesn't provide enough to run the Fenix, although it will keep the basic system running for appreciably longer than without it.  Once you throw in GPS the solar doesn't make much difference--the fact that on the 6 it's incompatible with the sapphire option didn't matter to me.

Comment: @bob1 Yes I am looking at the maps enabled versions.

Comment: @ChrisH Yes I have. The solar is not that great, unless at the beach. Going out for 2-4 weeks in new terrain, I have to have a power bank, and a solar panel charger too. Besides, at higher altitudes, I'd usually have at least 1 jacket on, so exposing the watch to the sun can be tricky too. And mountain weather is, more often than not, *bad*. Btw, the garminfenix subreddit https://www.reddit.com/r/GarminFenix/ seems lively, so I'm trawling through some old threads there rn. At least some folks on the sub seem to actively use the watch map. I guess its good in combination with a handheld device.

Comment: You might try catching more sun by strapping it on the outside or even on top of your pack - but the main thing is you're not going to get caught out

Comment: @ChrisH Practical test, admittedly very easy:  I had no problem at all using my Fenix to backtrack out of the wilderness.  Following the line was trivial.  (Admittedly, I was in a canyon, it would have been hard to get lost.)

Comment: @LorenPechtel that sounds reasonable - backtracking is a common and easy use case. My rerouting tends to be more of the shortcut variety, or going round impassable sections